# Reposition Camera View

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, camera-overlay

I have created and OverlayView for my UIImagePickerController.
Is there a way to reposition where the viewer shows up? Currently the viewer is pushed all of the way to one side of the device with a black box filling the remaining portion of the screen.

```
- (IBAction)presentCameraView:(id)sender {

_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

// Set flag to allow the alert to be shown
_showAlert = YES;
_endAlerts = NO;

_overlay = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CameraOverlay" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
_picker.delegate = self;
_picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
_picker.allowsEditing = NO;
_picker.cameraOverlayView = _overlay;
_picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
[self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: some code n screenshot pls.

Comment: what is problem in camera? the photo that you get from camera?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the picture. I simply want to move where the viewing area is. The portion that you look at when lining up your shot. I would like to more the area down and have a little black at the top and bottom rather than all of the black on the bottom.

Comment: check your overlay view then... your overlayview has to design that way...

Comment: you want camera like instagram... right?

Comment: My overlay only has the two buttons on it.

Comment: I think your overlayview also have this black box... else from where this black box comes?

Comment: The overlay definitely does not have the black box. I will edit the above post and put in a screen shot of it.

Comment: from where black box comes then?

Comment: Where does the black box come from in the default UIImagePickerController? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after a lot of looking I finally came across some stuff that allowed me to reposition the camera view as well as change the size of it.

```
CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 71.0); 
//This slots the preview exactly in the middle of the screen by moving it down 71 points

CGAffineTransform scale = CGAffineTransformScale(translate, 0.8888889, 1);
//This scales the view to the size that you want it.

_picker.cameraViewTransform = scale;
```